# Drawing outside graph borders

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am creating a d3 plot of some data and I would like to have zooming and panning capabilities. When I plot my data and zoom in or pan, the data can move outside the defined plot area without being clipped.

As you can see in the image, the orange dots appear on the green area when I would have expected them to be clipped.

[image]

Any ideas on what is wrong?

**Demo** at http://jsfiddle.net/ng6srz4o/

```
var dataX = [1,3,5,7,9];
var dataY = [0,2,4,6,8];

var margin, padding, outerWidth, outerHeight, innerWidth, innerHeight;
var xAxis, yAxis, xScale, yScale, svg, container, zoom, tooltip;

// assign the dimensions here, works the best
outerWidth = Math.ceil ($(window).width() * 0.90);
outerHeight = Math.ceil ($(window).height() * 0.55);

// distance of the outerRect from the innerRect
margin = { top: 16, right: 16, bottom: 32, left: 32 };

// distance of the actual data from the innerRect
padding = { top: 0, right: 32, bottom: 0, left: 32 };

innerWidth = outerWidth - margin.left - margin.right;
innerHeight = outerHeight - margin.top - margin.bottom;

xScale = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([ d3.min(dataX), d3.max(dataX) ])
    .range([ padding.left, innerWidth - padding.right ]);

yScale = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([ d3.min(dataY), d3.max(dataY) ])
    .range([ innerHeight - padding.bottom, padding.top ]);

zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
    .x(xScale).y(yScale)
    .scaleExtent([1, 20])
    .on ("zoom", onZoom);

svg = d3.select("#svgContainer")
    .append("svg:svg")
        .attr("width", outerWidth)
        .attr("height", outerHeight)
        .style("background", "green")
    .append("svg:g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
        .call(zoom);

drawAxis();

// white rect behind the graph
var rect = svg.append("svg:rect")
    .attr("width", innerWidth)
    .attr("height", innerHeight)
    .style("fill", "gray");

container = svg.append("svg:g");

var graph = container.append("svg:g").selectAll("scatter-dots")
        .data(dataY) 
    .enter().append("svg:circle")
        .attr("cy", function (d) { return yScale(d); })
        .attr("cx", function (d,i) { return xScale(dataX[i]); })
        .attr("r", 10)
        .style("fill", "orange");

function onZoom() {

    var t = d3.event.translate,
        s = d3.event.scale;

    container.attr("transform", "translate(" + t + ")scale(" + s + ")");

    svg.select(".x.axis").call(xAxis);
    svg.select(".y.axis").call(yAxis);
}

function drawAxis()
{
    xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(xScale)
        .orient("bottom");

    svg.append("svg:g")
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + innerHeight + ")")
        .style("fill", "blue")
        .call(xAxis);

    yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(yScale)
        .orient("left");

    svg.append("svg:g")
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        .style("fill", "red")
        .call(yAxis);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now, you have all of your points contained in a `g` element, which won't clip any of the points that you're drawing.

If you want to clip the points, you can add an `svg` element to your main `svg`, which will clip anything contained within, like so:

```
var mainSVG = d3.select('body').append('svg')
  .attr('width', outerWidth)
  .attr('height', outerHeight);

var innerSVG = mainSVG.append('svg')
  .attr('width', innerWidth)
  .attr('height', innerHeight)
  .selectAll('scatter-dots')
  ...
```

[(updated) fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/ng6srz4o/4/)

Comment: Just looked at the fiddle. I can still pan and zoom the points onto the green area.

Comment: Right now, your zoom behavior moves the `g` element that is the parent of the svg element I created. You need to move that element inside the inner svg in order for the zoom behavior to not move the svg around. See corrected fiddle.

Comment: Know I can only zoom and pan when the cursor is on one of the orange dots. If the cursor is on the gray area there is no panning and zooming.

Comment: I moved the `.call(zoom)` up to the `svg:rect` and it seems to be working.

Comment: In general, everything under whatever you put the `zoom` behavior on in the DOM will be able to be used as a zoom handle.